# Build a proper dataframe from a matrix list after importing .xlsx file

Tags: r, excel, dataframe, xlsx

**Implemented:**

I am importing a .xlsx file into R.
This file consists of three sheets.
I am binding all the sheets into a list.

**Need to Implement**

Now I want to combine this matrix lists into a single `data.frame`. With the header being the --> names(dataset).

I tried using the as.data.frame with `read.xlsx` as given in the help but it did not work.
I explicitly tried with `as.data.frame(as.table(dataset))` but still it generates a long list of `data.frame` but nothing that I want.

I want to have a structure like 
header = names and the values below that, just like how the read.table imports the data.

This is the code I am using:

```
    xlfile <- list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")
    wb <- loadWorkbook(xlfile)
    sheet_ct <- wb$getNumberOfSheets()
    b <- rbind(list(lapply(1:sheet_ct, function(x) {
             res <- read.xlsx(xlfile, x, as.data.frame = TRUE, header = TRUE)
})))
    b <- b [-c(1),] # Just want to remove the second header
```

I want to have the data arrangement something like below.

```
Ei  Mi  hours   Nphy    Cphy    CHLphy  Nhet    Chet    Ndet    Cdet    DON DOC DIN DIC AT  dCCHO   TEPC    Ncocco  Ccocco  CHLcocco    PICcocco    par Temp    Sal co2atm  u10 dicfl   co2ppm  co2mol  pH
1   1   1   1   0.1023488   0.6534707   0.1053458   0.04994161  0.3308593   0.04991916  0.3307085   0.05042275  49.76304    14.99330000 2050.132    2150.007    0.9642220   0.1339044   0.1040715   0.6500288   0.1087667   0.1000664   0.0000000   9.900000    31.31000    370 0.01    -2.963256000    565.1855    0.02562326  7.879427
2   1   1   2   0.1045240   0.6448216   0.1103250   0.04988347  0.3304699   0.04984045  0.3301691   0.05085697  49.52745    14.98729000 2050.264    2150.007    0.9308690   0.1652179   0.1076058   0.6386706   0.1164099   0.1001396   0.0000000   9.900000    31.31000    370 0.01    -2.971632000    565.7373    0.02564828  7.879042
3   1   1   3   0.1064772   0.6369597   0.1148174   0.04982555  0.3300819   0.04976363  0.3296314   0.05130091  49.29323    14.98221000 2050.396    2150.007    0.8997098   0.1941872   0.1104229   0.6291149   0.1225822   0.1007908   0.8695131   9.900000    31.31000    370 0.01    -2.980446000    566.3179    0.02567460  7.878636
4   1   1   4   0.1081702   0.6299084   0.1187672   0.04976784  0.3296952   0.04968840  0.3290949   0.05175249  49.06034    14.97810000 2050.524    2150.007    0.8705440   0.2210289   0.1125141   0.6213265   0.1273103   0.1018360   1.5513170   9.900000    31.31000    370 0.01    -2.989259000    566.8983    0.02570091  7.878231
5   1   1   5   0.1095905   0.6239005   0.1221460   0.04971029  0.3293089   0.04961446  0.3285598   0.05220978  48.82878    14.97485000 2050.641    2150.007    0.8431960   0.2459341   0.1140222   0.6152447   0.1308843   0.1034179   2.7777070   9.900000
```

Please dont suggest me to have all data on a single sheet and also convert .xlsx to .csv or simple text format. I am trying really hard to have a proper dataframe from a .xlsx file.

Following is the [file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B54s5NXDypdMaVF5QjVxeG4wUDA/view?usp=sharing)

And this is the post following : [Followup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26563042/reading-excel-file-into-r-and-merging-all-the-sheets-in-it-into-a-single-datafra)

This is what resulted:

```
str(full_data)
'data.frame':   0 obs. of  19 variables:
 $ Experiment : Factor w/ 2 levels "#","1": 
 $ Mesocosm   : Factor w/ 10 levels "#","1","2","3",..: 
 $ Exp.day    : Factor w/ 24 levels "1","10","11",..: 
 $ Hour       : Factor w/ 24 levels "108","12","132",..: 
 $ Temperature: Factor w/ 125 levels "10","10.01","10.02",..: 
 $ Salinity   : num 
 $ pH         : num 
 $ DIC        : Factor w/ 205 levels "1582.2925","1588.6475",..: 
 $ TA         : Factor w/ 117 levels "1813","1826",..: 
 $ DIN        : Factor w/ 66 levels "0.2","0.3","0.4",..: 
 $ Chl.a      : Factor w/ 156 levels "0.171","0.22",..: 
 $ PIC        : Factor w/ 194 levels "-0.47","-0.96",..: 
 $ POC        : Factor w/ 199 levels "-0.046","1.733",..: 
 $ PON        : Factor w/ 151 levels "1.675","1.723",..: 
 $ POP        : Factor w/ 110 levels "0.032","0.034",..: 
 $ DOC        : Factor w/ 93 levels "100.1","100.4",..: 
 $ DON        : Factor w/ 1 level "Âµmol/L": 
 $ DOP        : Factor w/ 1 level "Âµmol/L": 
 $ TEP        : Factor w/ 100 levels "10.4934","11.0053",..: 

  [Note: Above is the structure after reading from .xlsx file......the levels makes the calculation and manipulation part tedious and messy.]
```

This is what I want to achieve:

> str(a)

```
'data.frame':   9936 obs. of  29 variables:
 $ Ei      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Mi      : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ hours   : int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Cphy    : num  0.653 0.645 0.637 0.63 0.624 ...
 $ CHLphy  : num  0.105 0.11 0.115 0.119 0.122 ...
 $ Nhet    : num  0.0499 0.0499 0.0498 0.0498 0.0497 ...
 $ Chet    : num  0.331 0.33 0.33 0.33 0.329 ...
 $ Ndet    : num  0.0499 0.0498 0.0498 0.0497 0.0496 ...
 $ Cdet    : num  0.331 0.33 0.33 0.329 0.329 ...
 $ DON     : num  0.0504 0.0509 0.0513 0.0518 0.0522 ...
 $ DOC     : num  49.8 49.5 49.3 49.1 48.8 ...
 $ DIN     : num  15 15 15 15 15 ...
 $ DIC     : num  2050 2050 2050 2051 2051 ...
 $ AT      : num  2150 2150 2150 2150 2150 ...
 $ dCCHO   : num  0.964 0.931 0.9 0.871 0.843 ...
 $ TEPC    : num  0.134 0.165 0.194 0.221 0.246 ...
 $ Ncocco  : num  0.104 0.108 0.11 0.113 0.114 ...
 $ Ccocco  : num  0.65 0.639 0.629 0.621 0.615 ...
 $ CHLcocco: num  0.109 0.116 0.123 0.127 0.131 ...
 $ PICcocco: num  0.1 0.1 0.101 0.102 0.103 ...
 $ par     : num  0 0 0.87 1.55 2.78 ...
 $ Temp    : num  9.9 9.9 9.9 9.9 9.9 9.9 9.9 9.9 9.9 9.9 ...
 $ Sal     : num  31.3 31.3 31.3 31.3 31.3 ...
 $ co2atm  : num  370 370 370 370 370 370 370 370 370 370 ...
 $ u10     : num  0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 0.01 ...
 $ dicfl   : num  -2.96 -2.97 -2.98 -2.99 -3 ...
 $ co2ppm  : num  565 566 566 567 567 ...
 $ co2mol  : num  0.0256 0.0256 0.0257 0.0257 0.0257 ...
 $ pH      : num  7.88 7.88 7.88 7.88 7.88 ...
```

[Note: sorry for the extra columns, this is another dataset (simple text), which I am reading from read.table]

With NA's handled:

```
> unique(mydf_1$Exp.num)
[1] # 1
Levels: # 1
> unique(mydf_2$Exp.num)
[1] # 2
Levels: # 2
> unique(mydf_3$Exp.num)
[1] # 3
Levels: # 3
> unique(full_data$Exp.num)
[1] 2 3 4
```

Without handling NA's:

```
> unique(full_data$Exp.num)
[1]  1 NA  2  3
> unique(full_data$Mesocosm)
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 NA
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need. I add a few comments on what I am doing:

```
xlfile <- list.files(pattern = "*.xlsx")
wb <- loadWorkbook(xlfile)
sheet_ct <- wb$getNumberOfSheets()
for( i in 1:sheet_ct) {    #read the sheets into 3 separate dataframes (mydf_1, mydf_2, mydf3)
  print(i)
  variable_name <- sprintf('mydf_%s',i)
  assign(variable_name, read.xlsx(xlfile, sheetIndex=i,startRow=1, endRow=209)) #using this you don't need to use my formula to eliminate NAs. but you need to specify the first and last rows.
}

colnames(mydf_1) <- names(mydf_2) #this here was unclear. I chose the second sheet's
# names as column names but you can chose whichever you want using the same (second and third column had the same names).

#some of the sheets were loaded with a few blank rows (full of NAs) which I remove 
#with the following function according to the first column which is always populated
#according to what I see
remove_na_rows <- function(x) {
  x <- x[!is.na(x)]
  a <- length(x==TRUE)
}

mydf_1 <- mydf_1[1:remove_na_rows(mydf_1$Exp.num),]
mydf_2 <- mydf_2[1:remove_na_rows(mydf_2$Exp.num),]
mydf_3 <- mydf_3[1:remove_na_rows(mydf_3$Exp.num),]

full_data <- rbind(mydf_1[-1,],mydf_2[-1,],mydf_3[-1,]) #making one dataframe here
full_data <- lapply(full_data,function(x) as.numeric(x)) #convert fields to numeric
full_data2$Ei <- as.integer(full_data[['Ei']]) #use this to convert any column to integer
full_data2$Mi <- as.integer(full_data[['Mi']])
full_data2$hours <- as.integer(full_data[['hours']])

#*********code to use for removing NA rows *****************
#so if you rbind not caring about the NA rows you can use the below to get rid of them
#I just tested it and it seems to be working

n_row <- NULL
for ( i in 1:nrow(full_data)) {
  x <- full_data[i,]
  if ( all(is.na(x)) ) { 
    n_row <- append(n_row,i)
  }
}

full_data <- full_data[-n_row,]
```

I think now this is what you need

Comment: Thanks a ton. It helped, but the result is in terms of factors and levels. I have added the result into my question. Please check.

Comment: and btw the excel file you uploaded has only 19 variables and 209 rows on each spreadsheet :)

Comment: Yes absolutely...I have mentioned in my question last line .."[Note: sorry for the extra columns, this is another dataset (simple text), which I am reading from read.table]"...The excel sheet data is similar but with reduced data in it...:)

Comment: :P yeah sorry missed that line. I hope it helps now with the addition of those lines of code. If you re using a different excel which is slightly different maybe you need to modify some parts of my code but for the one you uploaded the above seems to work for me. Hope it helps!

Comment: let me know if sth doesn't work and I ll try to help

Comment: Thanks...You are removing the NA's row wise and this is making the columns are jumbled up somehow, so the data integrity will be gone at the step "rbind"...if I just bind the data without removing the NA's then the data integrity is fine, but ofcourse as you know NA will be added as one more value of that column. I have further added about this in the question, please check.

Comment: on the excel file you uploaded the column Exp.num was always filled in apart from the rows which were only NAs. this is why I used that function to exclude them. If in your original file there are lines that have NAs (in the middle of the column) then this function won't work.

Comment: The best thing to do in this case is to add startRow=NULL, endRow=NULL, these two parameters at the read.excel function. I ll update my answer.

Comment: Thanks! I ll also try to make a function later on today to remove a NA lines. you might find that useful too.

Comment: StartRow and endRow is one way, handling additional null columns in the beginning(file preparation) is one more way, but getting the last row of data and then then automating it is the best way...IMO..:) I will check on that...thanks for your help...:)

Comment: I know of a way to do that. I ll play with it a bit later on and repost if I get anything better :) thanks!

Comment: This is the full thing now I hope, after adding for the removal of NA rows (see code addition above). Hope it helps!